# How to change caption style for new float in memoir?

Tags: captions, memoir, newfloat

i defined a new float in memoir class. everything works fine, except i can't  manage to change the caption font style. if i declare `\captionnamefont{\bfseries}`, the font changes only for default float types, but not for the newly defined ones. see the image.

[image]

i used to achieve the desired result using 'caption' package. but i don't want to use it anymore, because i got several errors in memoir class.

thanks for your assistance.

edit: minimal example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir} 

\usepackage{float}

\captionnamefont{\bfseries}

\newcommand{\newfloatname}{NewFloat}
\newfloat{NewFloat}{nwf}{\newfloatname}[chapter]
\newlistentry{newfloat}{nwf}{0}


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \caption{Caption of original float.}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{NewFloat}[h]
        \caption{Caption of newly defined float}
    \end{NewFloat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you provide the code of a small but complete document that reproduces this problem? So it this case `\documentclass{memoir}`, any language options, the code you use for defining the new float type, code for setting the caption, `\begin{document}`, two example floats, `\end{document}`. That way it is much easier to reproduce the problem, to be sure what the problem is, and to start trying to find a solution.

Comment: The caption package works fine with memoir. So as Marjin says, please provide a full (but minimal l self contained example we can work with, so we can get a idea of what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for your help. it seems that the issue is caused by the float package. i managed to reproduce the error with just this package loaded. the minimal example in main post.

Comment: @user195690 that is another reason why we ask for minimal examples: often, in the process of making the example, the asker finds out what the problem is and many times also what the solution to that problem can be. It's a useful debugging technique as you have found out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) is causing the issue. Remove it and change the syntax to match that provided by [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) natively; it's similar, but different.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\newcommand{\newfloatname}{NewFloat}
\newfloat[chapter]{NewFloat}{nwf}{\newfloatname}

\captionnamefont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Caption of original float.}
\end{figure}

\begin{NewFloat}[h]
  \caption{Caption of newly defined float}
\end{NewFloat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great, thank you very much! i will just have to figure out, whether i am able to live without "H" placement specifier defined in float package.

Comment: @user195690: You can make your own `[H]` float. Here's a manual implementation: [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/Z84ffvuw)